# Google Analytics conversion code not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have enabled conversion tracking in Google Analytics. My analytics code is included on every page like this:

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-104000000-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments);
  }
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-104000000-1');
</script>
```

Despite it showing Tag Manager code, I actually got it through Analytics, and intentionally DID NOT use Google Tag setup.

I also added JS code on a page that the user will end-up after completing transaction. My code is added at the bottom of the page and looks like this:

```html
<script>
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '%invoice.public_id%',
    'revenue': ' %payment.amount%'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '%invoice.public_id%',
    'name': '%item.item_title%',
    'price': '%item.first_total%',
    'quantity': '%item.qty%'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

All the placeholder values populate properly, yet I don't get the conversion data trickle to the analytics. The rest of the analytics seem to be working just fine.

UPDATE: Also tried changing my code to the below one but still only visits an no e-commerce. I did check to make sure Enhanced e-commerce is enabled.

```
<script>
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        'transaction_id': '%invoice.public_id%',
        'value': '%payment.amount%',
        'items': [
            {
                'id': '%item.item_id%',
                'name': '%item.item_title%',
                'quantity': 1,
                'price': '%item.first_total%'
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider not posting your Google UA code?

Comment: It is not real ID - I've altered it for the example.

Comment: My guess: I need to replace ga with gtag. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Did you try moving the code to the header of your HTML file?

Comment: I can't. I use a plugin that places it at the bottom, before closing body tag. Also function gtag() is inserted at the very top, so I'm not sure this would be the reason for not reporting transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing the *gtag* code with the Universal Analytics (*ga*) code.
Here you can find documentation for Enhanced Ecommerce with gtag:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce

Another solution may be to use the Universal Analytics code instead gtag:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google- analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-104000000-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

So for ecommerce tracking you can use the snippet you are wrote in your post:

```
<script>
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '%invoice.public_id%',
    'revenue': ' %payment.amount%'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '%invoice.public_id%',
    'name': '%item.item_title%',
    'price': '%item.first_total%',
    'quantity': '%item.qty%'
  });
  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Comment: OK, I've, checked to make sure my Enhanced ecommerce is enabled and  replaced my code but still see no ecommerce results... Here's the code I put on my site:                        <script>
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "transaction_id": "%invoice.public_id%",
  "value": %payment.amount%,
  "currency": "USD",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "%item.item_id%",
      "name": "%item.item_title%",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '%item.first_total%'
    }
  ]
});
</script>

Comment: Seems to be correct (it could be a matter of time) anyway I changed my message by adding an alternative solution (which uses universal analytics instead of gtag, which is a manual replacement for GTM where the sent hits are still of universal analytics).

Comment: Have you tried with the Universal Analytics code instead of gtag or the data arrived with gtag?